# how did coordinate-handling in old flightsimulators work?

Tags: multiplayer, floating-point

Im currently working on a combat flight simulator pure for own fun.
Using a floating-origin i thought the float inprecision was history, however this was the case untill i tried adding multiplayer to the game.

The server is authorative and i'm banging my head around positioning the players on the server and handling the gun hits and collisions.

Using sectors i reset the origin of the clients but the server keeps the original position. This will lead into float inprecisions on the server, thus physic and collision checking are terrible.

Now i'm just wondering how games like Airwarrior, Warbirds and aceshigh overcame these problems. What approach did they use? I'm assuming something else. If only i was able to use double precision, or even fixed point, but i'm tied to a physics model working with floats. I don't feel like changing that around, unless i have no other option.

Thanks for any pointers.

stephan

Comment: Why have sectors on the client but not on the server. Any part of the simulation that is different for the server and the client can cause terrible bugs and should generally be avoided!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how those games solved it. But I just read the write up of how Dungeon Siege solved this for multiplayer was to keep things in their local region space and for each frame, turn things to a local space based off one region.

Therefore you don't have a single numerical space for the whole game.

You should take to time to read the write up. Super interesting.

Comment: +1 for Dungeon Siege reference. Interesting, i didn't know that. Is it the document you are talking about : http://floatingorigin.com/mirror/continuous-world.htm ?

Comment: Not the exact thing I read but it seems to cover the same key points.

Comment: This documentation probably points me into the right direction, and beside that, gives more handy tips. Great read.